# What is the time complexity of a nested loop with loop index not being reset?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
void fun(int n, int arr[]) {     
  int i = 0, j = 0;     
  for(; i < n; ++i)         
   {
     while(j < n && arr[i] < arr[j])             
     {
       j++; 
     }
   }
}
```

I'm having a torrid time dealing with time complexities. I didn't understand the execution of `while` loop.

Comment: when i=0 then execute while loop  remain not execute. j value is grater than n

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop i straightforward: it will be executed `n` times.

The inner one is a little tricky, because the value of `j` is capped at `n`, but it is never reset back to zero. That's why the body of the nested loop will be executed at most `n` times during the entire program. These `n` times may be spread across multiple iterations of the outer loop, but there will not be more than `n` of them.

Therefore, the time complexity of this code is O(n+n) = O(n).

The first `n` in O(n+n) is for the outer loop, and the second `n` is for the inner loop.